# Autocompletion always suggests files in the current directory

Tags: bash, autocomplete

When using autocompletion for any command which uses the built-in `_longopt` completion function (for example `mkdir`), the shell always suggests contents of the current directory in addition to the desired suggestions.

For example, if I type

```bsh
mkdir ~/somedir
```

and press tab two times Bash suggests: (assuming type current directory contains `applications`, `desktop`, etc.)

```
applications/   desktop/     documents/
...
somedir_a/      somedir_b/
```

How to restore normal behaviour and make bash only suggest `somedir_a` and `somedir_b` and not the other files/directories?

Bash version: `GNU bash, version 5.0.11(1)-release (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu)`
Bash-completion: `2.8`

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce with bash-completion 2.10 and Bash 5.0.16 (on Arch Linux). What is your bash-completion version? The behavior you're showing somehow resembles the bug described in [this comment](https://github.com/scop/bash-completion/issues/306#issuecomment-487294486) on GitHub, which apparently has been fixed in version 2.9.

Comment: You're right; it's fixed in the version 2.9 (which I only noticed after you posted). Unfortunately, 2.8 is the latest version that is packaged for Fedora as of now. I'll try to bug the packagers a bit so that they package a new version. Thanks for the info!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This behaviour can be caused by the shell option `nullglob`, which may be, for example, turned on in your `.bashrc`.

The reason is that the `_longopt` function has a bug in its definition, which causes this behaviour with `_longopt` turned on.

The solution is to disable this option or to override the `_longopt` function yourself.

A similar effect is also described here: [Why does nullglob affect tab completion?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/276930/why-does-nullglob-affect-tab-completion), although that question is quite hard to find unless you know that this option is at fault.

EDIT:
As pointed out by [@fra-san](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/315749/fra-san), this is a [known issue](https://github.com/scop/bash-completion/issues/306#issuecomment-487294486) with `bash-completion`. The fix has landed in version `2.9`, that version is however not yet shipped on Fedora (and perhaps other systems as well).