# What is the meaning of `*(1)*` in a command?

Tags: bash, filenames, wildcards

Why use of `*(1)*` removes everything from a directory? Then how to select all files that has `(1)` in the middle of it's name?

The command used is `rm *(1)*` or `rm -rf *(1)*` (don't remember exactly). It was default Ubuntu shell.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you have ksh-style extended globs enabled, e.g. with `extglob` set in Bash, then the pattern `*(1)*` indeed matches any filename. The `*(...)` syntax matches zero or more copies of the part in parenthesis, so any leading ones, if there are any. And then the `*` matches the rest.

If you were using a POSIX-like shell *without* extended globs, then that would be an error as the `(` operator doesn't fit into the syntax there.

In zsh by default, I think that's the same as `*1*`, i.e. the parenthesis just work for grouping. Though if you have the `kshglob` shell option set, then it uses ksh rules.

I think recent versions of Ubuntu set `extglob` in Bash by default in interactive shells.

To match files with a literal `(1)` part in the middle, quote or escape that part or at least the parens: either `*\(1\)*`, or `*"(1)"*`.

Comment: Do all distros have `extglob` set in Bash?

Comment: @YaY, probably not. You could use `shopt extglob` to see if it's enabled

Comment: @YaY not by default, as it can make a lot of bad things happen (see this question)

Comment: Related: [Is it dangerous to always have extglob on?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/276911/170373), and [Why would I not leave extglob enabled in bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17191622/6372809), where the consensus seems to be that it's not really dangerous. Ok, I guess the question here shows a possible gotcha. Though anyway, the parenthesis would need to be quoted in a standard shell, and if one does that, extended globs aren't at all dangerous. Anyway, they're on by default in ksh and mksh.

Comment: @OrangeDog what question? No link there. But I had it by default.

Comment: @YaY [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/727299/22005)